# Making available KR512PS10 datasheet

Tags: datasheet, reverse-engineering

I recently posted a question asking for information on the Russian divider IC KR512PS10 (as transliterated from Cyrillic), but nobody appeared to know anything about the device. I have now measured some of these ICs and have produced a brief datasheet to summarise what I have discovered. Where would be the best location to place this document (always assuming anybody is interested in this weird thing)? Does a generic datasheet repository exist?

Comment: If you type "datasheet" into Google, you get a few, like [this one](https://www.alldatasheet.com/).

Comment: If there's truly not some already out there, GitHub might honestly be a place. Put a text-based read me with it and if the repository is named well, Google will pick it up.

Comment: Not sure that this question is really on topic.  What you *should* do is post an answer to your original technical question summarizing your key findings and linking to any more extensive documentation you put on github or whatever.  You can (and should) answer your own question; your answer must have actual content here, and not just be a link.

Answer (score 1):

With thanks to the commentators, I have followed the suggestions and answered my original question.

The datasheet is available at https://github.com/henros32/KR512.